# While loop starts from beginning in tic tac toe game

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to write a tic tac toe game with java. In this game there are two player as A and B. Player A always starts the game(X),
and Player B is (O). I used random method to generate move numbers.

So, I created a while loop but it always start from beginning but I want to print a new board with latest move.

There's code below if you look at it and say what is the point that I am missing I will be glad.

Also singular numbers are belong to player A, plurals are belong to player B
I have to add +1 to whoseTurn for correct move(if random method tries to write X or O to a position has already taken, it must generate another row and column number but I couldn't figure it out as well)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe {

final static int SIZE = 5;
private static int row;
private static int column;

static Random number = new Random();
static char [][] array = new char[SIZE][SIZE];

public static void createBoard(){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("--------------");
}

public static void move(){
    int whoseTurn =1;
    while(whoseTurn <= (SIZE * SIZE)) {
        row = number.nextInt(6-1) + 1;
        column = number.nextInt(6-1) + 1;
        if ((whoseTurn % 2) != 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                    array[i][j] = '#';
                    array[row-1][column-1] = 'X';
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------");
            whoseTurn +=1;
        } else if((whoseTurn % 2) == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                    array[i][j] = '#';
                    array[row-1][column-1] = 'O';
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            whoseTurn += 1; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you refactor the nonenglish words it would be a lot easier to grasp the logic and help you with the error.

Comment: @melanzane, ı've edited it. Thanks.

Comment: If you right click on your variable in your editor, go to refactor -> rename. This operation will rename every occurrence of this variable in your code. There are still variables like 'hamleSayısı' and its not compiling.

Comment: @melanzane I've changed them also, sorry. It is forbidden to use IDE or something else. I am using Apple's standart textEdit app.

Comment: You need to save the state of the board. You need to have some sort of information of what the history of moves were, for example a two-dimensional array to store those values, so you can use them to print them out in every step. The way your code works now, you're just generating a new move with every step and putting the newly generated X and O, and filling the renamings of the board with #

Comment: @user3362334 So I have to define a new array and assign the latest value to store them am i correct? If i am, how will i use in loop or is it have to be outside the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You loop refilled the board for every move of the user with # and the one move of the user, namely 0 or X. By just replacing the one position in the board instead of modifying the whole board, all the previous moves are safed and will be printed.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe {

    final static int SIZE = 5;
    private static int row;
    private static int column;


    static Random number = new Random();
    static char[][] array = new char[SIZE][SIZE];


    public static void createBoard() {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                array[i][j] = '#';
            }

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }


    public static void move() {

        int whoseTurn = 1;

        while (whoseTurn <= (SIZE * SIZE)) {


            row = number.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;

            column = number.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;


            if ((whoseTurn % 2) != 0) {

                array[row - 1][column - 1] = 'X';

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("--------------");

                whoseTurn += 1;

            } else if ((whoseTurn % 2) == 0) {

                array[row - 1][column - 1] = 'O';

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("--------------");

                whoseTurn += 1;
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The random number you generate for the row/column can at some point replace a move that already is there. In the next step you'll need to remove the already taken spots from from the choices your random has.
This is how you enrich your random with specific choices: 
   private int[] items = new int[]{0,1};
    private Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(items.length);

Comment: Thank you so much, I saw my mistake. Being a beginner is really annoying :)  but I don't want to replace it with already taken spots. İf random method tries to place an already taken position it has to generate a new column and row number. How can I add this to program? I thought  [link]if((row != #) && (column != #)) then generate a new number but ı don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep table state somewhere.

It could be done like this:

You create a Pair class that holds coordinates of the symbols:

```
public class Pair {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Pair() {}

    public Pair (int x, int y) {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Pair pair) {
        return pair.getX() == this.x && pair.getY() == this.y ? true : false;
    }

}
```

You then could then make your own ArrayList implementation that will make checking if the history already contains the coordinates much easier:

```
public class PairList extends ArrayList<Pair>{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7047628156984387721L;

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        for (Pair pair : this) {
            if (pair.getX() == x && pair.getY() == y) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And, finally your TicTacToe class would look something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe {

    final static int SIZE = 5;
    private static int row;
    private static int column;

    static Random number = new Random();
    static char[][] array = new char[SIZE][SIZE];

    public static void createBoard() {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                array[i][j] = '#';
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }

    public static void move() {

        int whoseTurn = 1;

        PairList boardStatusX = new PairList();
        PairList boardStatusY = new PairList();

        while (whoseTurn <= (SIZE * SIZE)) {

            do {

                row = number.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;

                column = number.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;

            } while (boardStatusX.contains(row, column) || boardStatusY.contains(row, column));

            if ((whoseTurn % 2) != 0) {

                boardStatusX.add(new Pair(row, column));

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                        if (boardStatusX.contains(i, j)) {
                            array[i][j] = 'X';
                        }

                        else {
                            array[i][j] = '#';
                        }

                    }
                }

                //array[row - 1][column - 1] = 'X';

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("--------------");

                whoseTurn += 1;
            }

            else if ((whoseTurn % 2) == 0) {
                boardStatusY.add(new Pair(row, column));

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                        if (boardStatusY.contains(i, j)) {
                            array[i][j] = 'Y';
                        }

                        else {
                            array[i][j] = '#';
                        }

                    }
                }

                //array[row - 1][column - 1] = 'Y';

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("--------------");

                whoseTurn += 1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but it is too complicated. I am learning java for about 7 weeks and it is my homework. Therefore it is forbidden to use that we didn't see such as ArrayList

Comment: Okay, sorry for not being of help than. Anyway, you can achieve this by using multi-dimensional array to store the history. I will try to code it and update my answer then

Comment: I just added another answer with simpler solution. I hope that helps. I works and avoids X and O being overwritten

Comment: thank you so much for your interest :) I will look at it and try to learn from code. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution that works, and checks if the field is already taken(placed 'X' or 'Y') so it doesn't overwrite the existing X and O.

It is based on @melanzane's answer:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe {

    final static int SIZE = 5;
    private static int row;
    private static int column;

    static Random number = new Random();
    static char[][] array = new char[SIZE][SIZE];

    public static void createBoard() {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                array[i][j] = '#';
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }

    public static void move() {

        int whoseTurn = 1;

        while (whoseTurn <= (SIZE * SIZE)) {

            do {

                row = number.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;

                column = number.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;

            } while (array[row][column] == 'X' || array[row][column] == 'Y');



            if ((whoseTurn % 2) != 0) {

                array[row - 1][column - 1] = 'X';

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("--------------");

                whoseTurn += 1;

            } else if ((whoseTurn % 2) == 0) {

                array[row - 1][column - 1] = 'O';

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("--------------");

                whoseTurn += 1;
            }

        }
    }

}
```